# Show original image pixels instead of mask in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have a deep learning model which returns to me an array which when plotted like this

```
res = deeplab_model.predict(np.expand_dims(resized2,0))
labels = np.argmax(res.squeeze(),-1) #remove single dimension values, gives the indices of maximum values in the array  
plt.imshow(labels[:-pad_x])
```

(the last line above just removes some unclear lines before plotting them)

looks like this
[image: masked output]

original image is like this

[image: original image]

when I do the

```
print(labels[labels>0])
print(labels.shape)
print(len(labels))
```

I get this

```
[12 12 12 ... 12 12 12]
(512, 512)
512
```

I want to show the colored pixels in the original image where mask appears and turn everything else to black (or blur or some other color I'll choose), how can I do that?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please check the closing lines of the post?

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: So you see that there is a mask for Dog and a Cat in yellow color
Instead of that yellow color I need to show the real dog and cat
Hope it makes sense?

Comment: Now i understand

Comment: Whats `deeplab_model`?

Comment: Its a deep learning model, details of that is irrelevant just know that it returns the 'res' array but if you're interested here's the lib https://github.com/bonlime/keras-deeplab-v3-plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reverse this and achieve what I wanted to get

`mask = labels[:-pad_x] == 0
resizedOrig = cv2.resize(frame, (512,384))
resizedOrig[mask] = 0`

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how the labels array works here. Assuming that it contains values greater than zero where the cat and dog are, you can create the masked image with something like,

```
mask = lables > 0
newimage = np.zeros(image.shape)
newimage[mask] = image[mask]
```

where I've create a zero image based on the original and set the original pixels where the labels are greater than zero.

Comment: Yes the labels array contains values greater than 0 where the mask is. I tried your solution 
`newImage = np.zeros(img.shape)
 newImage[mask] = img[mask]`

but I get this error 

`IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 358 but corresponding boolean dimension is 512` 

where img is `img = plt.imread("imgs/image2.jpg")`

when I do a check they both have the same dimensions 
`print(img.shape, newImage.shape)`
`(358, 500, 3) (358, 500, 3)`

Comment: Hang on a sec, I was actually trying to create a mask on the original image instead of the resized one so after trying 

`newImage = np.zeros(resized2.shape)
newImage[mask] = resized2[mask]`

I get this image https://imgur.com/a/Q3eszkJ 
with a message 
`Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)`