# How to show masked foreground image into background image of different size

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

Further to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336074/show-original-image-pixels-instead-of-mask-in-python/) I like to put a video frame in the background of the extracted masked foreground pixels
My foreground frame is `resizedFrame[mask]` where mask is essentially `mask = labels == 0` and `labels` contains indices of pixels with values greater than `0` [image: output of prediction]

I want to be able to put a video in the background, the video frame I'm reading from the file using OpenCV VideoCapture in python, the video is of different size than the foreground image

I have tried `background.paste(foreground, box)` approach using `PIL.Image` but it doesn't help with a masked foreground image

Comment: Just read the video file using [cv2.videoCapture()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=get#videocapture-videocapture), it would get you each frame and then you can simply use the solution from your previous question.

Comment: But the video and foreground are not same size so masking on background gives me error

Comment: For any image processing operation to take place between matrices, they must be of same size, It is just like you are trying to do `"5" + 2`, which would give you error, as the data type(s) for the `+` operands are not same. Similarly OpenCV raises error in case the dimensions of matrices are not same, To prevent this you can either resize the matrices or do adaptive padding for aligning width first or height first.

Comment: Thanks, could you please show me a code example?

Comment: That's why I was asking for a sample frame and your mask image without these scaling marks so that I can reproduce the same scenario on my local machine

Comment: I re-read your comments but you never asked me for those? I will try to save them and share

Comment: Oops, Sorry my bad, maybe i mixed up the context of two different posts, never mind